# Send data from ESP32 to Processing via wifi

Tags: arduino, processing, wifi, esp32

I was trying to connect ESP32 (client)-Processing (server) and I think I made it work, but server doesn't receive or print anything. Why processing doesn't recognise when client is connected? I am new to Processing and trying to undrestand how it works.

**Processing:**

```
import processing.net.*;

Server myServer;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  // Starts a myServer on port 5204
  myServer = new Server(this, 5204); 
  println(Server.ip());
}
void serverEvent(Server someServer, Client someClient) {
  println("We have a new client: " + someClient.ip());
}
```

**ESP32:**

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "myNetwork";
const char* pass = "myPassword";

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(10);
    WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);

    Serial.print("Connecting.");
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.print("WiFi connected - IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    delay(500);
}

void loop()
{
    const uint16_t port = 5204;
    const char * host = "10.0.26.xx";

    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);

    // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
    WiFiClient client;

    if (client.connect(host, port)){
      Serial.println("Sending data"); // printed on serial monitor
      client.print("Hello");
    }

    // This will send a request to the server
    client.print("Send this data to the server");

    Serial.println("Closing connection.");
    client.stop();
}
```

**EDITED**

[image: IDE serial monitor]

It gives the same prints even if I don't run the processing program. So is it connected somewhere else instead of the server?

At the processing I am getting only that *"The value of parameter someServer is not used"*

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the debug info you see on the serial console?

Comment: Thanks, I wrote an answer, I cannot guarantee it will work right away but maybe it can put you on the right track. I can understand your troubles here, processing's documentation is not that complete or clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *I figured out*. It was a *firewall* issue. I **disable** the firewall and then it worked. Also, before that I created a new rule for the Processing and the Port but for some reason it didn't work I don't undrestand why. *Disabled it was the solution to my problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Your *processing* code is missing the part where you retrieve data from the client.

You need to add something like this:

```
void draw() {
    // Get the next available client
    Client thisClient = myServer.available();
    // If the client is not null, and says something, display what it said
    if (thisClient != null) {
        String whatClientSaid = thisClient.readString();
        if (whatClientSaid != null) {
            println(thisClient.ip() + "t" + whatClientSaid);
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/Server_available_.html)

I don't see any other obvious issues but I cannot test something similar to your setup right now. Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: Thank you @Marcos G. but it was a firewall issue after all. See my answer if interested. :)